# Using a conditional statement in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, median

I am trying to find the median of some prices whereby another column matches,

ie,

```
Prices          Type of product

1                Bananas
4                Peas
9                Bananas
20               Beans
5                Bananas
90               Apples
```

I know how to pull the median price for all of them as a group, but I need Excel to show me what the median price is for apples, what the median price is for peas and what the median price is for bananas based on my list of produce (a conditional median expression).

Anything that could help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer on http://superuser.com same format as stackoverflow, but a different focus.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `VLOOKUP` function to get your dataset for the `MEDIAN`.

Info on VLOOKUP is [here](http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/general/learning_vlookup_in_excel).